# In smarty, is it possible to include a conf files into another conf file

Tags: php, smarty, config, smarty3

I'm using smarty for my project. I used config files for displaying labels in order to support different language. I store the label text in different config files with language prefix.

**en_common.conf**

```
FIRST_NAME = "First Name"
LAST_NAME = "Last Name"
...
```

**en_student.conf**

```
BATCH = "Batch"
YEAR_OF_PASSING = "Year of passing"
...
```

**en_teacher.conf**

```
DATE_OF_JOINING = "Date of joining"
EXPERIENCE = "Experience"
QUALIFICATION = "Qualification"
...
```

It will load depends upon user selected language (ie. if user select english, "en" is assigned to "lang" and then if student module will display means moduleName is assigned as "student".

**Student.php**

```
$smarty->assign('lang', $_COOKIE['lang']);
$smarty->assign('moduleName', $_POST['moduleName']);
```

**Student.tpl**

```
{config_load file="{$lang}_{$moduleName}.conf"}
```

For every template, i will load only one config file. In this, i need to include en_common.conf to both en_student.conf and en_teacher.conf. In order to use en_common.conf for every needed module.

**en_student.conf**

```
{config_load file="en_common.conf"} #its throw a parsing error
BATCH = "Batch"
YEAR_OF_PASSING = "Year of passing"
...
```

I want to know, is their is any way to config_load in **conf** file itself....

*Note*: Please dont say use another config_load in "tpl"(smarty templates) or configLoad("en_common.conf") in smarty object, it will work but i need to do manipulation only in **conf** file. Thanks...

Comment: No, you can't do that.

Comment: There is no way to do this in config files. Advanced loading configuration files you may only do in Smarty object

Comment: Thanks both of you for your response. I just use smarty object to load the common config file.